# URL to product page with quantity inputed - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to edit a product url in WooCommerce so that when visited a quantity is pre-selected for the quantity input, e.g. 2.

I know there is an add to cart url for it:

```
http://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=47&quantity=2
```

But was wondering if it was possible to just input the quantity on the product page with a similar URL.

Thanks for any ideas on the matter.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_woocommerce_quantity_input_args' ); // Simple products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_woocommerce_quantity_input_args' ); // Variations

function custom_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['qty'] ) && is_numeric($_GET['qty']) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = $_GET['qty'];
    }
    return $args;
}
```

with that you can then do `http://yourdomain.com/product/ship-your-idea/?qty=10`.